# After uploading MVC website to the folder httpdocs from FIlezilla and browsing it the showing Internal Server error

Tags: cpanel, filezilla

I am getting 500 Internal server.I have uploaded files to the server using Filezila .and when i am browsing it.Its showing internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

Whats is the permission of your files and directory's which you have uploaded in your account. Also check your .htaccess file code.

Answer (score 0):

There may be several reasons , let me list few which i think might be the reason.

1) Check the folder and file permissions on the hosting . Folder permission should be `755` and the file permission should be `644` by default to work on

2) If there is any `.htaccess` file try to remove that file and check again reloading (***Note :*** if you are using cPanel try selecting show hidden files in file manager to view the .htaccess file )

3) whether your `db` is been properly configured in the configuration file of your MVC site ( however if it is the reason the page will will throw some db connectivity error . just in case if it is i am asking you to check )

If that helps, update me . If not, Kindly post the error log which can be taken in cPanel or if you are using different solution ask your hosting provider on how to view error log.

Answer (score 0):

The best and universal approach if you have root access on the server would be to look for more information in the web server log:

/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log

If you do not have root access, you can check the Error log in cPanel -> Errors, it will provide you with more details on what the problem is.